# Не работает обтекание слева

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Почему не работает обтекание слева для class="sidebar"

```css
/* Убираем отступы у списка */

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ol {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 960px;
  height: 1271px;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 330px;
  height: 1271px;
  float: left;
}

.sidebar_photo {
  margin: 100px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.sidebar_writers {
  margin: 52px 0 30px 0;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: rgb(21, 169, 139);
  font-family: "Georgia";
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar_writers_item {
  margin: 19px 0 0 20px;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
  font-family: "Georgia";
}

.sidebar_films {
  margin: 60px 0 24px 0;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: rgb(21, 169, 139);
  font-family: "Georgia";
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar_films_item {
  margin: 19px 0 0 16px;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
  font-family: "Georgia";
}

.content {
  width: 630px;
  height: 1271px;
}

.content_photo {}

.content_quote {}

.content_title {}

.content_item {}

.content_link {}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <img class="sidebar_photo" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/40KxF.jpg" alt="">
    <h1 class="sidebar_writers">Любимые писатели</h1>
    <ul>
      <li class="sidebar_writers_item">Пабло Неруда</li>
      <li class="sidebar_writers_item">Рубен Фонсека</li>
      <li class="sidebar_writers_item">Исабель Аленде</li>
      <li class="sidebar_writers_item">Симоне Бевуар</li>
    </ul>
    <h1 class="sidebar_films">Любимые фильмы</h1>
    <ol>
      <li class="sidebar_films_item">Чикаго (2002)</li>
      <li class="sidebar_films_item">Дни жатвы (1978)</li>
      <li class="sidebar_films_item">Бумажная луна (1973)</li>
      <li class="sidebar_films_item">Сталкер (1979)</li>
    </ol>
    <div>
      <!-- sidebar -->
      <div class="content">
        <div class="content_photo">
          <!--<img src="images/hook.jpg" alt="">-->
        </div>
        <div>
          <blockquote>
            <p class="content_quote">"If you have a procedure with ten parameters, you probably missed some."</p>
          </blockquote>
        </div>
        <h1 class="content_title">Jackie Chan</h1>
        <p class="content_item">Люди считают меня оптимистичным, инициативным членом команды с отличными навыками общения. Последние несколько лет я занимаюсь подготовкой руководящих кадров, работаю в сфере телемаркетинга и обслуживания клиентов в разных отраслях промышленности.
          Я обладаю опытом успешного назначения людей на должности уровня начальников технологических отделов и подготовки эффективных руководителей. В моем послужном списке – поддержание постоянного объема назначений и мероприятий. Кроме того, я постоянно
          вхожу в первую десятку по объему продаж и мог бы делать то же самое для вашей компании</p>
        <h3 class="content_title">Мои увлечения...</h3>
        <p class="content_item">изучаю восточную культуру, языки; увлекаюсь оригами; занимаюсь художественным переводом книг; реставрирую старинные церкви и здания; выходные дни провожу на раскопках исторических поселений; уделяю время сбору мусора на пляжах, в лесах, лесопосадках;
          благоустраиваю свой город; рисую мультипликационные фильмы; создаю развивающие книги для детей.</p>
        <a class="content_link" href="URL">напиши мне</a>
        <div>
          <!-- content -->
          <div>
            <!-- wrapper -->
```

Comment: если закрывающий для .sidebar перед .content , то забыли поставить слеш

Comment: @St1myL влияет ваще то

Comment: @St1myL смотри - закрыл тег : https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/xWbwaj?editors=1100

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, странно, у себя попробовал, ничего не вышло

Comment: @St1myL можешь ответ написать

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, пожалуй не буду, оставлю эту возможность другим

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Таг **sidebar** не закрыт ...

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ol {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 960px;
  height: 1271px;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 330px;
  height: 1271px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.sidebar_photo {
  margin: 100px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.sidebar_writers {
  margin: 52px 0 30px 0;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: rgb(21, 169, 139);
  font-family: "Georgia";
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <img class="sidebar_photo" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/40KxF.jpg" alt="">
    <h1 class="sidebar_writers">Любимые писатели</h1>
    <ul>
      <li class="sidebar_writers_item">Пабло Неруда</li>
      <li class="sidebar_writers_item">Рубен Фонсека</li>
      <li class="sidebar_writers_item">Исабель Аленде</li>
      <li class="sidebar_writers_item">Симоне Бевуар</li>
    </ul>
    <h1 class="sidebar_films">Любимые фильмы</h1>
    <ol>
      <li class="sidebar_films_item">Чикаго (2002)</li>
      <li class="sidebar_films_item">Дни жатвы (1978)</li>
      <li class="sidebar_films_item">Бумажная луна (1973)</li>
      <li class="sidebar_films_item">Сталкер (1979)</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <!-- sidebar -->
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content_photo">
      <!--<img src="images/hook.jpg" alt="">-->
    </div>
    <div>
      <blockquote>
        <p class="content_quote">"If you have a procedure with ten parameters, you probably missed some."</p>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
    <h1 class="content_title">Jackie Chan</h1>
    <p class="content_item">Люди считают меня оптимистичным, инициативным членом команды с отличными навыками общения. Последние несколько лет я занимаюсь подготовкой руководящих кадров, работаю в сфере телемаркетинга и обслуживания клиентов в разных отраслях промышленности.
      Я обладаю опытом успешного назначения людей на должности уровня начальников технологических отделов и подготовки эффективных руководителей. В моем послужном списке – поддержание постоянного объема назначений и мероприятий. Кроме того, я постоянно
      вхожу в первую десятку по объему продаж и мог бы делать то же самое для вашей компании</p>
    <h3 class="content_title">Мои увлечения...</h3>
    <p class="content_item">изучаю восточную культуру, языки; увлекаюсь оригами; занимаюсь художественным переводом книг; реставрирую старинные церкви и здания; выходные дни провожу на раскопках исторических поселений; уделяю время сбору мусора на пляжах, в лесах, лесопосадках;
      благоустраиваю свой город; рисую мультипликационные фильмы; создаю развивающие книги для детей.</p>
    <a class="content_link" href="URL">напиши мне</a>
    <div>
      <!-- content -->
      <div>
        <!-- wrapper -->
```